# T-SQL Multiple duplicates check

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, partitioning

I'm facing this problem - I have this kind of select result:

```
col1 col2           col3
5    95.91.232.198  1
8    95.91.232.198  1
9    95.91.222.206  5
152  95.91.222.206  1
25   95.91.204.108  5
5    95.91.204.108  5
```

- column3 can have only 2 values: 1 or 5

I want to select only those rows which have different numbers in `column3` with duplicated ip - example (what should be selected):

this should be selected

```
127.0.0.1   1
127.0.0.1   5
```

and this not

```
127.0.0.1   1
127.0.0.1   1
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: "Hope i've explained well myself"  No one understand you.  What is this "select only those rows who will after check if col2 (ip) have only 1 in col3" even mean???

Comment: Please adjust the column names so can see `ip` in the first table. Also, please show us results  that do correspond to your sample data (as they stand, they do not seem related).

Comment: edited, hope now it will be clear ;)

Comment: Your expected results are using different IP addresses to your starting data... so its really not clear what you are asking...

Answer (score 0):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where col2 = t.col2 and col3 <> t.col3
)
```

Or if you want only the ips:

```
select col2
from tablename
group by col2
having count(distinct col3) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DISTINCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-distinct-with-select) keyword to select only unique combinations of values.

Starting data:

```
col1 col2 col3
5   95.91.232.198   1
8   95.91.232.198   1
9   95.91.222.206   5
152 95.91.222.206   1
25  95.91.204.108   5
5   95.91.204.108   5
```

Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col2, col3
FROM [table]
```

Output:

```
col2 col3
95.91.232.198   1
95.91.222.206   5
95.91.222.206   1
95.91.204.108   5
```